# Better way to determine if a button is clicked

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am developing a game in MonoGame and decided to create my own button class. In order to determine if these buttons were clicked, I determined if they were in the bounds of the button, and if the left mouse button was down. This has lead to two problems.

1. The mouse click doesn't need to start inside the button, and it registers immediately rather than after the mouse button is released (Inside the bounds of the button.)
2. When multiple buttons on different screens are in the same area, it results in clicking them both as the mouse button did not release fast enough.

How can I make the clicking behave more like the WinForm buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make mouseclicking work effectively you should do the following :

First thing we do is create a MouseInput class, this should track stuff like, mouseState, lastMouseState, MouseX, MouseY. The mouseState and lastMouseState work together to handle 1 single click. But for now you can just add this class to your project :

```
class MouseInput
    {
        private static MouseState mouseState;
        private static MouseState lastMouseState;


        public static MouseState MouseState
        {
            get { return mouseState; }
            set { mouseState = value; }
        }

        public static MouseState LastMouseState
        {
            get
            {
                return lastMouseState;
            }
            set
            {
                lastMouseState = value;
            }
        }

        public MouseInput()
        {
        }
        public static int getMouseX()
        {
            return Mouse.GetState().X;
        }

        public static int getMouseY()
        {
            return Mouse.GetState().Y;
        }
    }
```

After you've done that you want to start loooking for a mouseclick everytime your update method gets executed :

```
 MouseInput.LastMouseState = MouseInput.MouseState;

  // Get the mouse state relevant for this frame
 MouseInput.MouseState = Mouse.GetState();
```

After you've completed these 2 crucial steps you can continue and use your code anywhere you want like this :

```
if (MouseInput.LastMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && MouseInput.MouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) {
 //Execute code here
}
```

Ofcourse as the above if statement only checks if the player pressed the left mouse button, you'll still have to check if the mouse positions are inside the button.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`RoutedEvent`** that can invoke handlers on multiple listeners in an element tree, rather than just on the object that raised the event. you can read more about [**RoutedEvents**](http://wpftutorial.net/RoutedEvents.html) because The concept of an **attached event** enables you to add a handler for a particular event to an arbitrary element rather than to an element that actually defines or inherits the event. When those events are not related to the element which, like in case of `MouseDown`, both raises and listens to the event.

So RoutedEvents might help you to solve your problem

Here is a sample code

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent SelectedEvent = 
    EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent( "Selected", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
    typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyCustomControl));

// .NET wrapper
public event RoutedEventHandler Selected
{
    add { AddHandler(SelectedEvent, value); } 
    remove { RemoveHandler(SelectedEvent, value); }
}

// Raise the routed event "selected"
RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MyCustomControl.SelectedEvent));
```

Comment: Wow. That went over my head.Could you explain that in simpler terms?

Comment: did you read the link provided. Try to implement in a test project to see how it works and I am sure it would be going to help in your project too.

Answer (score 0):

UI for XNA 4.0 [like WinForms](https://bitbucket.org/prostokiriuha/utils/src/59403d4e3c1efab5f4f5603bae3cca29616a60ed/GameHelper/Graphics2D/UI/?at=master), written from scratch.

Create form and, button to it, call Form.Update() from Game.Update() method.
In Game.Draw() first call Form.Refresh(), then Form.Draw().

For processing mouse and keyboard input used managers from GameHelper.Input library.